# ARM Assembly - "Expression too complex" or "lo register required" with stmfd sp!, [lr]

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I am learning assembly, in particular for ARM processors.

This is my very simple assembly code:

```
            .data
integer:    .long   25

        .text
        .global main
main:   stmfd sp!, [lr]
        ldr r0, =integer
        ldr r1, [r0]
        add r1, #2
        str r1, [r0]
        ldmfd sp!, [lr]
        mov pc, lr
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:6: Error: expression too complex -- `stmfd sp!,[lr]'
test.s:11: Error: expression too complex -- `ldmfd sp!,[lr]'
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error..searched a lot, but couldn't find anything..

Comment: What are you intending the exclamation mark on the left operand to do?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what this instruction does.I am following an example from a book.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what's supposed to be going on.  The right-hand operand should be a list of registers whose values should be loaded or stored, but the ARM assembler expects such a list to be enclosed in `{}` rather than `[]`.

Comment: Tried with `{}`. This time:
`Error: lo register required -- stmfd sp!,{lr}`

Comment: In ARM mode, using `{}` works, and disassembles back to `e92d4000   stmfd   sp!, {lr}`.  In `.syntax unified` / `.thumb_func` / `.cpu cortex-m3`, I can do `e923 0003       stmdb   r3!, {r0, r1}`

Comment: @PeterCordes, if I add `.cpu cortex-m3`, `.thumb_func`, and `.syntax unified` it compiles fine, but I don't understand why

Comment: In case this remained unclear to OP: "Lo registers", "Hi registers" are explained [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/c/overview-of-the-arm-architecture/register-accesses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STore Multiple / LoaD Multiple instructions take a *list* of registers, enclosed in `{}` not `[]`.

In ARM mode, `stmfd sp!, {lr}` assembles just fine, and disassembles back to
`e92d4000   stmfd   sp!, {lr}` with `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d`

---

In Thumb mode, push/pop are separate instructions with their own mnemonic and opcodes.
e.g. `b500  push    {lr}`.  Use that because it's more efficient (when your register list includes only registers in r0..r7, lr.)

`stmfd` exists in Thumb-2, but GAS only handles it properly in `.syntax unified` mode, apparently.  Without that, `stmfd sp!,{lr}` gives an `Error: lo register required`.

But with `.syntax unified` we get  `f84d ed04  str.w  lr, [sp, #-4]!`, and in combination with other registers we can do things like `e929 4803    stmdb   r9!, {r0, r1, fp, lr}` which clearly uses non-lo registers for both the address and in the register-list, and disassembles as the `stmdb` mnemonic.  (FD = full descending  is the same as DB = Decrement Before, for stores.)

e.g. I put this into `foo.s` so I could run `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c` on it.  (`gcc -mthumb` doesn't appear to matter for assembling, only compiling C).

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb_func

  stmfd r3!, {r0, r1}             @ different error message, but still only unified syntax
  stmfd r9!, {r0, r1, r11, lr}    @ only in unified
  stmfd sp!, {lr}                 @ only in unified
  push {lr}
```

Without `.syntax unified`, we get

```
foo.s: Assembler messages:
foo.s:5: Error: Thumb-2 instruction only valid in unified syntax -- `stmfd r3!,{r0,r1}'
foo.s:6: Error: lo register required -- `stmfd r9!,{r0,r1,r11,lr}'
foo.s:7: Error: lo register required -- `stmfd sp!,{lr}'
```

The first error message may be the key to the mystery of GAS's other error messages: **Thumb-2 instruction only valid in unified syntax**.

Perhaps GAS in split parsing mode mode just checks register numbers for being `lo` before verifying that the mnemonic is even valid at all for that mode.  **So we're probably getting error messages based on applying Thumb 1 rules to a Thumb2-only instruction.**

**TL:DR: always use `.syntax unified`**, the default is dumb.